# AuthGuard not working properly in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, auth-guard

In My Application I am redirecting to the Home Page on successful login ,

- when user logs in I am setting `isLoggedIn` to true in local storage
- but when I refresh the home page it redirects to Login page again, but the `isLoggedIn` is still set to true.

```html
      <form (ngSubmit)="onLogin()" name="loginForm" [formGroup]="loginForm">
        <div class="userInput">
          <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>UserID</mat-label>
            <input
              formControlName="name" matInput placeholder="Enter User ID" required/>
            <mat-error *ngIf="!loginForm.controls['name'].valid">
                UserID is required
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
            <a class="text-link" class="aLink" routerLink="/auth/forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
          </span>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
            <input formControlName="password" matInput [type]=" hide ? 'password' : 'text'" required />
            <button  mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide Password'"
            [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
            <mat-icon>
                {{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}
            </mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-error *ngIf="!loginForm.controls['password'].valid">
            Password is required
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <button mat-flat-button style="background-color: #16bca8">Login</button>
</form>
```

Above is my **login.component.html**

```
redirecting(){
    this.userService.logIn();
    const observer= {
        next: (x:any) => {console.log(x)}, 
        error: (err: any) => {console.log(err.error)}
    }
    this.http.get(this.url,{responseType: 'text' ,withCredentials: true}).subscribe(observer);
    
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
  }

  onLogin() {
    let body = {
      "username": username,
      "password": password
    }
    const observer = {
      next: (x: any) => {console.log(x);this.redirecting()}, 
      error: (err: any) => {console.log(err.error)}, 
      complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'),
    }
    this.http.post(url, body, { responseType: 'text', withCredentials: true }).subscribe(observer);
  }
```

Above is my **login.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("loggedin") === "true";
    }
    loggedIn():boolean {
        return this.isLoggedIn || this.isRegistered;
    }
    logIn() {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        localStorage.setItem("loggedin", "true");
    }
```

Above is the **service** which I am using

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree 
    {
    
        if (this.userService.loggedIn()) {
            console.log("Authorized");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("Not Auhtorized");
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Above is the **auth.guard.ts**

```
{ path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'professor', component: ProfessorComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
}
```

I have added the above routes in application.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your AuthGuard is ok. Sure it can be written better, but it is working. But in refresh the service is returning false for the loggedIn().

On your service you're calling onInit to check local storage if logged in.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("loggedin") === "true";
}
```

`OnInit()` will not work for services please see [Lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Why don't you just get the logged info from local storage in the function instead? (Or use constructor instead on OnInit)

```
loggedIn():boolean {
 return localStorage.getItem("loggedin") === "true";
}


logIn() {
 localStorage.setItem("loggedin", "true");
}
```